# Mysql Left outer join in my Query for optimize

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database table name called "tablestr table" and "restbookingtable":

**tablestr:**

str_id is primary key

[image]

**restbooking:**
bookingsection_id is foreign key

[image]

in booking table i storing str_id multiple values with comma separated and My query is

```
SELECT `str_id` FROM (`rest_tablestr`) WHERE str_id NOT IN (
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.bookingsection_id, ",", n.n), ",", -1) value FROM rest_restaurantbooking t 
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n FROM (
SELECT 0 AS N
UNION ALL
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 6 
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 8 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 9) a , (
SELECT 0 AS N
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 5 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 6 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 7 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 8 
UNION ALL SELECT 9) 
b ORDER BY n ) n 
WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.bookingsection_id) -
LENGTH(REPLACE(t.bookingsection_id, ",", ""))) AND
t.res_id = 21 AND
t.booking_status not in ("cancelled","departed","noshow") AND
((t.bookingstart_time <= "2015-06-12 19:45:00" AND t.bookingend_time >= "2015-06-12 22:15:00") OR 
(t.bookingend_time >= "2015-06-12 19:45:00" AND t.bookingend_time <= "2015-06-12 22:15:00") OR
(t.bookingstart_time >= "2015-06-12 19:45:00" AND t.bookingstart_time <= "2015-06-12 22:15:00") OR 
(t.bookingstart_time >= "2015-06-12 19:45:00" AND t.bookingend_time <= "2015-06-12 22:15:00")) ) AND
`res_id` = '21' AND
`area_id` = '28' AND 
`wait_table` = 'no' AND
`availability` = 'yes';
```

**Result Set:**

[image]

Can any body help me to rewrite query with left outer join or can be optimize query.

Comment: Your foreign key is a CSV? I don't think so! See normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry foreign key name is bookingsection_id . But i am saving str_id values in bookingsection_id.

Comment: Fix your data structure to use a separate junction table, the right way to store lists of numbers in a relational database.  Also, don't call a column a "foreign key" if the rules of the language prevent you from declaring it as a foreign key.